# I'd like to know whether my post is well written or not

Tags: support, questions, review, formatting

I have a question about my Super User post: [I can't map a network share from PXE - WinPE](https://superuser.com/questions/1753517/i-cant-map-a-network-share-from-pxe-winpe)

I have written a question yesterday and I'd like, if someone can help, to know whether my question is well-written/following the site standards, or not. I've been reading some FAQs in the superuser help center, about questions (Specially, **How do I ask a good question?**). I think my question is Ok, but I would like if someone with more experience than me, could give me a well documented point of view. If it has some kind of error, or even if it's entirely erroneous, I'm willing to work on it, and rewrite, if necessary. Because I'd like to setup my iPXE server and also I'm enjoying the technical experience.
Also, I have read somewhere, don't remember where, that there is a normalized questions scheme, in technical IT forums, like:

I have a home installation like *this* and *this* and *technical information*.

I want to achieve *this* and *all the information about what you want to achieve*.

I have tried *this* and *this* ...

So, how could I continue? ...

That is what I said about a scheme for questions. I have not read something like that in the FAQ about questions in superuser. So Is there some scheme like this, or it is more free, meaning I can structure it as I naturally would write it? obviously I am clear about the **How do I ask a good question?** points.

For example, in my post I wrote the technical stuff at the end, but I don't know If I should have written it at the beggining, or I'm free to write it anywhere, as I did.

Comment: The questions looks fine to me.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - Those are normal.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - I have seen them before.  I didn't think the ""ask a question" guide mechanic was on meta super user but it appears something like that would create.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 See [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274518/a-way-for-new-users-to-ask-about-their-post-specifically) for details.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 And thanks for pointing it out - I had never seen it before either!  I was curious, so I Googled something like *"stack exchange" "Questions not about your post will be deleted"* and found the MSE post.